# prove smoothness of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am trying to do Exercise 2.66 in Jeffrey Lee's book on differential manifolds. There is one step that escapes me, and I think it reduces to the following problem. Let $g:U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a continuous function, where $U$ is an open and connected neighbourhood of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Assume that $$x\rightarrow\sum_{i=1}^{n}g_{i}(x)\frac{\partial{}f}{\partial{}x_{i}}(x)$$ is smooth (infinitely differentiable) for all smooth $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Show that $g$ is smooth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $f=x_i$, the coordinate projection, so that $x\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^{n}g_{i}(x)\frac{\partial{}f}{\partial{}x_{i}}(x)=g_i(x),$ which is smooth by assumption. It follows that $g$ is smooth because each $g_i$ is.

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help!